# must I connect my cat5e cable wall box the same way as the RJ45 plug

Tags: cat5e

The shop I bought my patch cable from connected the Rj45 plug as O, O/W, G, G/W, Bl/W, Bl,Br/w Br.

How do I connect it on the wall box?

Comment: good to include a pic though you don't have rep. But I am vaguely familiar with what you're talking about. It's like when you have lots of computers and you have a thing on the wall with all the RJ45 sockets, and to connect two computers together you connect one socket to another socket on the wall area. I guess you're asking how to wire it. Straight through or crossover. Why don't you try it for two sockets. I'd guess straight through and a crossover will work.. and you use a crossover cable to connect the two.

Comment: Yes its a P8PC wire connected as I said in the post. Need to know if I must wire the wall box/point (not sure of the right terminology here) in the same order. (unable to upload images). I have already made a patch cable connected the same way that I will run from the wall socket to a PC.

Comment: It's really not difficult to find information about cat5 cabling on the internet.

Comment: My worry is not finding information on the CAT5 wiring as I am aware of how it should be done. I just don't have the money to fork out for a call out fee to come and rewire and already laid cable. The P8PC connection was done incorrectly I need to know if I must wire the wall box in the same way for the termination point to work.

Comment: You have had not just one, but two, close votes. I strongly suggest that you include some pics. If the links don't go in somebody can always edit it and fix it. But try to.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's 8P8C, not P8PC. Also, it's a patch cable? If so, why not just buy a new one?

Comment: You can buy a crimper to crimp the other side yourself for $10 (http://www.dx.com/p/191335). 8P8C connectors are usually quite cheap too (the latest I got I think I paid for them like 0.20€/pc. or so)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

- Connect the patch cord to the wall jack (as a user) and write down which color will connect to which pin.
- Cut the patch cord and connect the colored cable heads to pins according to what you have written in the previous step

Answer (score 0):

A Cat-5e cable for Ethernet should be connected to the 8P8C modular connector as per the EIA/TIA 568-B.

There's lots of images with the schema on the internet, but the pairing is:
2' 2 3' 1 1' 3 4' 4, with the ' meaning the second cable in the pair.

As per the coloring standard on cable pairs, the pairs are numerated as such:

1. Blue
2. Orange
3. Green
4. Brown

The second cable of the pair is white-striped.

So the colors should be, with the pins looking at you and with the hole in the P8PC connector towards you, from left to right, O/W, O, G/W, Bl, Bl/W, G, Br/W, Br.

If your cable does not follow EIA/TIA 568-{A,B}, my opinion is that you should buy another modular connector and patch both cables according to the standard.

Wiring the connector straight (maybe 1 1' 2 2' 3 3' 4 4') may increase crosstalk issues.

Comment: Can I wire to the wall socket as I have indicated I am quite happy with the standard problem is (silly me) never checked to see if the shop wired correctly so I have already laid the cable. Just need to know if i connect the wires the same way to the wall point (socket) will it make a difference if I then use a patch cable connected the the same way running from the wall socket to a pc

Comment: Just to be clear, it's 8P8C, not P8PC.

Comment: @joeqwerty yikes. My brain just crosswired the characters :). Edited to avoid confusion, thanks!

Comment: @chips in TIA 568-B the wiring is straight, but the pairs are not connected "in order". That's to reduce crosstalk, and it may prevent you to reach 1000BaseT compatibility (thus, the wiring should not be called Cat. 5e, even if the patch cable follows it).

Comment: @chips you should follow the standard. But if you really really can't do and you absolutely must not replace the wire nor the modular connector and still live with it, use a multimeter to be certain of the wiring order. But it may not work due to crosstalk. Rewiring the modular connector is a better idea if you can afford it.